# Change variable via selected item in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So I learning Kivy but I am stuck with the `ListView` or, as the `ListView` seems to be deprecated, the `RecycleView`.

My problem is that I want the label with `species_text` as ID to change based on the item I click on, once in the label is in view.

The documentation helped me as far as making the `SelectableLabel` and being able to click / color it, but I do not know how to change the text of `species_text` via the data list of the `RecycleView` or how to save the data list in the `ScreenTest` class.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label, Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""

<ScreenTest>:
    Label:
        pos_hint: {"x": .45, "top": 1}
        text: "Headline"
        size_hint: .1, .1


    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.02, "top": .8}

        RecycleView:
            id: species_list_view
            data: [{'name': "Species1", "text": "S1"}, {'name': "Species2", "text": "S2"}]
            viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

            SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                orientation: 'vertical'
                multiselect: False
                touch_multiselect: False

        Label:
            id: species_text
            text: "Speciestext"

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        spacing: 10

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .2, .1, 1
            Rectangle: 
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"

        Button:
            text: "Next"


<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
""")


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class ScreenTest(Screen):
    pass


screen_manager = ScreenManager()
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTest(name="screen_test"))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager


test_app = TestApp()
test_app.run()
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply_selection()` method has `RecycleView` arguments, taking into account that we can create a property that has the selected text, and then we make a bind with the text of the `Label`:

```
    ...
    RecycleView:
        id: species_list_view
        data: [{'name': "Species1", "text": "S1"}, {'name': "Species2", "text": "S2"}]
        viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
        text_selected: "" # create property

        SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
            ...

    Label:
        id: species_text
        text: "Speciestext" if not species_list_view.text_selected else species_list_view.text_selected # apply binding
    ...

 def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
    self.selected = is_selected
    if is_selected:
        print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        rv.text_selected  = rv.data[index]['text'] # set text
    else:
        print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also for the if clause in the Label, I did not know that this works o.o

Answer (score 0):

When you select the SelectableLabel you must find the "species_text" Label and change its text.
One way to do that is from its "apply_selection" method.

```
    if is_selected:
        for screen in App.get_running_app().root.screens:
            if screen.name == "screen_test":
                screen.ids.species_text.text = rv.data[index]["name"]
```

P.S. There is a typo in the kv code:
The "touch_multiselect" attribute is written "touc_multiselect"